# How can I make a TextBox in a GridView not fire TextChanged when SelectedIndexChanged is fired?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox, selectedindexchanged

I have a `TextBox` in a `TemplateField` in a `GridView` that is supposed to show a checkmark after its `TextChanged` event.

I also made the `GridView` row selectable.  If I select a row, the entire `GridView` rebinds and fires the `TextChanged` event for all `TextBoxes` in the `GridView`. This, of course, displays all the checkmarks.

I don't want to display the checkmarks on any rows the user did not change.  I think the best way to do this is to prevent (unattach?) the `TextChanged` event unless the user changes the text value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem!

Comment: Could you please tell more about what exactly you're doing in the textchanged event and gridview select row event?

Comment: Try to handle the event and use e.Cancel? With more info I could give you more specific direction, but this seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i've understood your problem actually because you haven't provided any source-code, but i try to give an answer anyway.

There are several options to avoid this behaviour:

1. set the TextBox' `AutoPostback`-Property to `true`. On this way the TextChanged-Event will occur directly after the user entered something into the Textbox and presses *Enter* or leaves the Textbox' focus
2. You should hide the CheckMarks by default(`Visible="false"`)
3. You must not rebind the GridView `OnSelectedIndexChanging` but only set it's `SelectedIndex` to `e.NewSelectedIndex`. On this way the Text of the Textboxes which was already been changed by the user will not be overwritten from the old db-values

Here's a simple example to demontrate what i mean:

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridSelecting" OnRowDataBound="GridRowDataBound" >  
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="LightBlue" />
    <columns>   
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckMark" Checked="true" Enabled="false" visible="false" runat="server" />
               <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" OnTextChanged="TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>         
    </columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        BindGrid();
    }
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    DataTable source = new DataTable();
    source.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(string)));
    DataRow row = source.NewRow();
    row["Value"] = "A";
    source.Rows.Add(row);
    row = source.NewRow();
    row["Value"] = "B";
    source.Rows.Add(row);
    row = source.NewRow();
    row["Value"] = "C";
    source.Rows.Add(row);
    this.GridView1.DataSource = source;
    this.GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var chk = ((TextBox)sender).NamingContainer.FindControl("CheckMark");
    chk.Visible = true;
}

protected void GridSelecting(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    this.GridView1.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
}
```

*Note: I'm sure that the original OP meanwhile has found the answer or a workaround by himself, maybe it'anyway   helpful for someone else to see the differences between this simplified working sample and his own code*